# div class doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css

I have to build a website for school and I am having trouble with a div class.

I wanted a new div for blog posts but it doesn't seem to work. If you take a look at my css you see that I changed the height but the text didn't move down. I called the div class 'first' and wrote some text to see where it would end up.

```css
body {}


/*---- website---*/

#header {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  color: white;
  background-color: #98AFC7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
}


/*----lost een bug op die li en ul laat verdwijnen----*/

.clearfix:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/*----- Menu -----*/

.menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  left: 120px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.menu {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: #D7D7D7;
}

.menu li:hover>a,
.menu .current-item>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 0%;
}


/*----- basis menu -----*/

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #70879F;
}


/*-----2e menu-----*/

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 160%;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #70879F;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background: #98AFC7;
}

.first {
  margin: 600px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Home.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="first">
    tekst-tekst
  </div>

  <div id="header">
    <center><big>No strings attached</big></center>
  </div>

  <!--menu-->
  <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">

        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="current-item"><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Webshop <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Gitaren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Electronica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Overig</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Over mij</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you explain better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you have this on header `position: relative;
    top: 10px;`

Comment: Which of the three divs is the problematic one?